# Ruby and mutexes

Tags: ruby, multithreading, mutex

I have a multi-threaded application. I have three shared resources. Different threads will call those resources simultaneously. I need to have a mutex for that. Will one mutex be enough, or should I create a mutex for every resource? Will it speed up when using many mutexes?

Comment: None of the threads ever require more than one resource at a time?

Comment: No, one thread requires one resource at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the resources are independent of eachother, there is no reason to guard them all with a single Mutex.  You will be starving other threads of access to resources that they could safely use.

Use one Mutex per resource if possible.

wrt performance - Threads accessing the shared resources are more likely to perform well if the resources are independently guarded as opposed to having a single, shared Mutex - but it depends on many more factors than just this.

Comment: I suspect that the OP is worried about deadlock if threads need to acquire more than one resource at a time?

Comment: In which case the [Dining Philosophers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem) problem applies and he needs to ensure threads always acquire and release locks on resources in the same order.